# Using python, how to check if every line of a text file has the same format?

Tags: python, file

Let's take this file for example:

```
Black_Panther;500;130;120;110

Tomb_Raider;75;112;102;92

Pacific_Rim;400;126;116;106
```

How do I control in python if the file looks like this:

```
Black_Panther;500;130;120;110

Tomb_Raider;75;112;102;92

Pacific_Rim;400;126;116;
```

(the 106 is missing in the last line).
How do I make python alert me when one of the lines is not following the same format as the other lines? In this case, when 106 was removed from the file.
Basically I want Python to alert me when one of the lines in the text files doesn't have 5 columns as the others.
I've been stuck with this problem and can't solve it.

thanx for any help

Comment: what is your file type ? and these are each line of your file ?

Comment: Another way would be to use a regex like [a-zA-Z\_]+(;[0-9]+){4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file.txt looks like this :

```
Black_Panther;500;130;120;110
Tomb_Raider;75;112;102;92
Pacific_Rim;400;126;116;
```

You can do like this :

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
   for i in f:
       if len(i.strip(';').split(';')) != 5:
          print("exception in", i)
          Do what you want to ....
```

Comment: You can correct your code for this `;400;126;116;106;` condition. It didn't mention the it but may face the same.

Comment: @Akhilesh appreciate that one :)

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of columns in a line you can use `os` package is the following manner:

```
import os

line = "Pacific_Rim;400;126;116;106"
elements_in_line = line.strip(";").split (";")
number_of_columns = len(elements_in_line)

if number_of_columns != 5:
    print ("It's a warning")
```

Here, the function [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split), splits the string.

Comment: Is it? It works for me. But yeah! if you prefer, use `!=`.

Comment: Anyway, I have corrected `is not` as `!=` as per your suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure its working when `line = "Pacific_Rim;400;126;116;"`

Comment: @VikasDamodar, You are correct, I really made a silly mistake by avoiding `;` in the end of the line. I will try to correct it ASAP.

Comment: @VikasDamodar, I have corrected it. Big thanks for you suggestion.